# "-webkit-background-size" is not a known CSS property name. Visual Studio 2022

Tags: css, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have this error for my CSS file in ASP.NET Core visual studio 2022

```
Warning     "-webkit-background-size" is not a known CSS property name. myproject   D:\Users\Amir ESH\source\repos\myproject\myproject\wwwroot\css\main.css 172 


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     "-moz-background-size" is not a known CSS property name.    myproject   D:\Users\Amir ESH\source\repos\myproject\myproject\wwwroot\css\main.css 173
```

I have this code on that lines

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
```

Comment: remove them, you don't need prefixes with background-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning messages are almost correct.

Whereas -webkit-background-size was implemented on early versions of Safari and -moz-background-size was on FF, both implementations were of an earlier standards definition and importantly in your case neither implemented cover.

See https://caniuse.com/?search=-webkit-background-size

Answer (score 0):

This problem can have several causes:

1. If Visual Studio 2022 is lower than 17.0.0 Preview 3.1 it is stated on the Visual Studio IDE official community page that the latest released version should be installed to fix this issue.
2. This issue can occur if ASP.NET Intellisense is not installed in Visual Studio 2022.
3. This issue may occur because a third-party plugin such as [CSS3 Intellisense Schema](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mojtabakaviani.CSS3IntellisenseSchema) that provides CSS3 support is not installed on the Marketplace.

**NOT:** Since Visual Studio 2022 is still in preview version, there is no plugin that is compatible with Visual Studio 2022 version, can solve this problem, and provides CSS3 support, in my query on Marketplace.

---

###### References

- [No Intellisense CSS Classes Names for Bootstrap vs 2022 Preview](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/no-intellisense-css-classes-for-bootstrap-vs-2022/1477893)

Comment: I Installed that but my problem was not fixed. I use visual studio 2022.

Comment: no, I have visual studio Enterprise 2022 version 17.0.4

Answer (score -1):

If you add **Web Essentials** your problem will hopefully be solved

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebEssentials2019

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2022 this is for Visual Studio 2019

Comment: and also try it http://vswebessentials.com/

Comment: @PremSignh Dev Essentials plugin does not support [CSS AutoPrefixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aa2c6125-2973-4efb-b891-4415b9b0a54b.WebEssentials).